# the list items in my main-nav of my website are sticking together using flex box? i want space between them

Tags: html, css, web

```
<header class="main-header">
     <h2 class="name">Student Name</h2>
     <ul class="main-nav">
       <li>
         <a href="">Home</a>
       </li>
       <li>
         <a href="">Portfolio</a>
       </li>
       <li>
         <a href="">Contact</a>
       </li>
     </ul>
</header>

@media only Screen and (min-width: 768px){
  .main-header,
  .main-nav {
    display: flex;
  }
  .main-header {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
  }
}
```

I wanted my list items to be in-line on the center of the page and seperated from each other when I have a 768px breakpoint. however the list items stick together (end to end). They are not overlapping just sticking.

Answer (score 0):

Add a width to them as follows.

```
<style>
@media only Screen and (min-width: 768px){
  .main-header,
  .main-nav {
    display: flex;
  }
  .main-header {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
  }
 .main-nav li
    {
    width:100px;
     } 
}
</style>
<header class="main-header">
     <h2 class="name">Student Name</h2>
     <ul class="main-nav">
       <li>
         <a href="">Home</a>
       </li>
       <li>
         <a href="">Portfolio</a>
       </li>
       <li>
         <a href="">Contact</a>
       </li>
     </ul>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a desired width to your '.main-nav' and since you're using flex, set justify-content to space-between.

```
@media only Screen and (min-width: 768px){
  .main-header,
  .main-nav {
    display: flex;
  }
  .main-header {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .main-nav {
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 400px;
  }
}
```